# Fitting a dataset to a mix of normal distributions

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, statsmodels, scipy.stats

In my application, the input dataset often comes from a Gaussian distribution. But, sometimes it is multimodal, and in those cases, I would like to model the data as a mix of data from multiple Gaussian distributions.

Now, I want to arrive at an estimate for the mean and sigma of the many underlying distributions.

I could not find a way to do this.

One way I am thinking is to split the data set into multiple. I will use a Gaussian KDE and use the minima as the points to split. But, it is not going to be accurate in the regions where underlying distributions overlap.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For future: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate place for statistical questions.

There's no need to split the data set into multiple. Looks like scipy already has this covered: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html there if you look at Kernel density estimation and bimodal distribution version

```
def my_kde_bandwidth(obj, fac=1./5):
    """We use Scott's Rule, multiplied by a constant factor."""
    return np.power(obj.n, -1./(obj.d+4)) * fac

from functools import partial


loc1, scale1, size1 = (-2, 1, 175)

loc2, scale2, size2 = (2, 0.2, 50)

x2 = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(loc=loc1, scale=scale1, size=size1),

                     np.random.normal(loc=loc2, scale=scale2, size=size2)])


x_eval = np.linspace(x2.min() - 1, x2.max() + 1, 500)


kde = stats.gaussian_kde(x2)

kde2 = stats.gaussian_kde(x2, bw_method='silverman')

kde3 = stats.gaussian_kde(x2, bw_method=partial(my_kde_bandwidth, fac=0.2))

kde4 = stats.gaussian_kde(x2, bw_method=partial(my_kde_bandwidth, fac=0.5))


pdf = stats.norm.pdf

bimodal_pdf = pdf(x_eval, loc=loc1, scale=scale1) * float(size1) / x2.size + \

              pdf(x_eval, loc=loc2, scale=scale2) * float(size2) / x2.size



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)



ax.plot(x2, np.zeros(x2.shape), 'b+', ms=12)

ax.plot(x_eval, kde(x_eval), 'k-', label="Scott's Rule")

ax.plot(x_eval, kde2(x_eval), 'b-', label="Silverman's Rule")

ax.plot(x_eval, kde3(x_eval), 'g-', label="Scott * 0.2")

ax.plot(x_eval, kde4(x_eval), 'c-', label="Scott * 0.5")

ax.plot(x_eval, bimodal_pdf, 'r--', label="Actual PDF")



ax.set_xlim([x_eval.min(), x_eval.max()])

ax.legend(loc=2)

ax.set_xlabel('x')

ax.set_ylabel('Density')

plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting image]

Here the x2 is the modeled data and... maybe there's better explanation in the document page.

Comment: In my case, I want to predict loc1, scale1, loc2, scale2 for the given observation. I still could not figure out how to do that. Not sure if I am missing something.